# trace a particular IP and port

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, network-programming

I have an app running on port 9100 on a remote server serving http pages. After I ssh into the server I can curl localhost 9100 and I receive the response.

However I am unable to access the same app from the browser using `http://ip:9100`

I am also unable to telnet from my local PC. How do I debug it? Is there a way to traceroute a particular IP and port combination, to see where it is being blocked?

Any linux tools / commands / utilities will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, check the IP address that your application has bound to. It could only be binding to a local address, for example, which would mean that you'd never see it from a different machine regardless of firewall states.

You could try using a portscanner like nmap to see if the port is open and visible externally... it can tell you if the port is closed (there's nothing listening there), open (you should be able to see it fine) or filtered (by a firewall, for example).

Comment: Rook, Thanks for your reply. How do I check the IP binding?

Comment: Also when I do nmap it only displays open ports, what option do I use to display all ports?

Comment: Well, without knowing anything about your application it is impossible to say! Have a look through its configuration file, perhaps? You could try looking at the output of `netstat -lt`... an application bound to a local address will show up as "tcp localhost:9100", for example.

Comment: Thanks Rook that was the problem it was only bound to the local IP.

Answer (score 74):

You can use the default `traceroute` command for this purpose, then there will be nothing to install.

```
traceroute -T -p 9100 <IP address/hostname>
```

The `-T` argument is required so that the TCP protocol is used instead of UDP.

In the rare case when `traceroute` isn't available, you can also use `ncat`.

```
nc -Czvw 5 <IP address/hostname> 9100
```

Comment: Great! Note that you need root rights to perform that command

Answer (score 31):

```
tcptraceroute   xx.xx.xx.xx 9100
```

if you didn't find it you can install it

```
yum -y install tcptraceroute
```

or

```
aptitude -y install tcptraceroute
```

Comment: Homebrew has a package for this little gem of a tool as well. `brew install tcptraceroute`. You do need to sudo to use the tool however.

Answer (score 14):

you can use [`tcpdump`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump) on the server to check if the client even reaches the server.

```
  tcpdump -i any tcp port 9100
```

also make sure your firewall is not blocking incoming connections.

EDIT: you can also write the dump into a file and view it with wireshark on your client if you don't want to read it on the console.

2nd Edit: you can check if you can reach the port via

```
 nc ip 9100 -z -v
```

from your local PC.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by using this command: `tcptraceroute -p destination port destination IP`. like: `tcptraceroute -p 9100 10.0.0.50`  but don't forget to install tcptraceroute package on your system. tcpdump and nc by default installed on the system. regards

Answer (score 0):

If you use the 'openssl' tool, this is one way to get extract the CA cert for a particular server:

`openssl s_client -showcerts -servername server -connect server:443`

The certificate will have "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" and "END CERTIFICATE" markers.
If you want to see the data in the certificate, you can do: "openssl x509 -inform PEM -in certfile -text -out certdata" where certfile is the cert you extracted from logfile. Look in certdata.
If you want to trust the certificate, you can add it to your CA certificate store or use it stand-alone as described. Just remember that the security is no better than the way you obtained the certificate.

https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

After getting the certificate use keytool to install it.